# Regex Match all numbers and hyphen if hyphen is in between numbers

Tags: regex

```
Example string: 80 http, 135 epmap, 139 netbios-ssn, 443 https, 445 microsoft-ds, 1433 ms-sql-server, 3389, 5985, 8530, 10123, 49000-49999, 50000-59999, 60000-65535, 61003, 62959
```

I want to remove all text and hyphens if the hyphen is surrounded by text and keep the hyphen if it is in a number range. If I use like ^0-9^- it will keep all hyphen, even if it is in a range. I can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
Outcome string example : 80, 135, 139, 443, 445, 1433, 3389, 5985, 8530, 10123, 49000-49999, 50000-59999, 60000-65535, 61003, 62959,
```

Comment: `^0-9^-` is a wrong pattern and you won't get any match with it. What is the real pattern you tried?

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below regular expression will help you in solving your problem.

`\d+-?\d*`

Exploding description:

- \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

  **+ Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     -? matches the character - literally (case sensitive)

  **? Quantifier** — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

  *** Quantifier** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     Global pattern flags
     g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
     m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
\d+-?\d*
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` matches as many digits as it can
- `-?` optionally we match a `-`
- `\d*` this part will only match the rest of the numbers after the hyphen. If there isn't a hyphen, `\d+` at the start would have matched every digit

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O91agg/1)

Answer (score 0):

*This works:*

Find `[\S\s]*?(\d+(?:-\d+)*)[^\d]*`
Replace `$1,`

https://regex101.com/r/ar2HoB/1

Readable version

```
 [\S\s]*?  
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      (?: - \d+ )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^\d]*
```

Answer (score 0):

In your outcome string you expect also words without hyphens to be removed.

To get to the outcome string this pattern can be of help for you.

```
 ?[a-z-]+(?!\d)
```